# find the probability density function of $f(Y)$ if $Y=X_1+X_2$

Tags: probability, statistics, density-function

$X_1$ and $X_2$ are samples from the homogenous distribution $[0,\theta]$ with $\theta > 0$ an unknown parameter. 
show that the density function of $Y= X_1 + X_2$ is given by:

$f_Y(y) = \left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  \frac{y}{\theta^2} \;\; 0 \leq y \leq \theta\\
                  \frac{2\theta-y}{\theta^2} \;\; \theta \leq y \leq 2\theta\\
                  0 \;\; elsewhere
                \end{array}
              \right.$

My approach has been: 
$P(X_1 \leq y-X_2)= \int_0^{2\theta}(\int_0^{y-x_2} f(x_1)f(x_2)dx_1)dx_2 = \frac{y-x_2}{{\theta}^2}$ which is nowhere near what the question is suggesting. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You did not carry out the integration w.r.t. $x_2$. The value of the double integral depends only on $y$ and $\theta$; it cannot be a function of $x_2$.

Comment: Ah yes I see I jumped too fast to a conclusion. But even when I perform the second integral I get to $\frac{2\theta y - 2\theta^2}{\theta^2}$ getting close but not quite yet. Am I using the wrong borders?